# responsiveness in grid error while using styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components

I'm making my portfolio where i have made a react component where i will be using grids from responsiveness. The Grid contains 2 columns, one contains the profile photo and the other contains my skills progress bar.
My grid works just fine on computer screens, but as soon as the screen size shrinks to less than 768px,
the second column suddenly becomes invisible.

below is my react code:

```
import React from 'react'
import img from '../../images/1cut.png'
import {
  AboutContainer,
  AboutWrapper,
  AboutRow,
  Column1,
  Column2,
  ImgWrapper,
  Img,
  TextWrapper,
  TopLine,
  Heading,
  Progress,
  ProgressDone,
} from './aboutMe2Elements'
const AboutMe2 = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <AboutContainer id='about'>
        <AboutWrapper>
          <AboutRow>
            <Column1>
              <ImgWrapper>
                <Img src={img} alt='Profile Photo' />
              </ImgWrapper>
            </Column1>
            <Column2>
              <TextWrapper>
                <TopLine>My Skills</TopLine>
                <Heading>Frontend Development</Heading>
                <Progress>
                  <ProgressDone width={85}></ProgressDone>
                </Progress>
                <Heading>Backend Development</Heading>
                <Progress>
                  <ProgressDone width={75}></ProgressDone>
                </Progress>
                <Heading>Data Structures and Algorithms</Heading>
                <Progress>
                  <ProgressDone width={69}></ProgressDone>
                </Progress>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Column2>
          </AboutRow>
        </AboutWrapper>
      </AboutContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default AboutMe2
```

Here is my styled components code:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const AboutContainer = styled.div`
  color: #fff;
  background: #010606;
  @media screen and(max-width:768px) {
    padding: 100px 0;
  }
`
export const AboutWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 24px;
  justify-content: center;
`
export const AboutRow = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-areas: 'col1 col2';
  @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    grid-template-areas: 'col1 ' 'col2';
  }
`
export const Column1 = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  grid-area: col1;
`
export const Column2 = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  grid-area: col2;
`

export const ImgWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 555px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #010606;
`
export const Img = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10;
  background: #010606;
  padding-right: 0;
`

export const TextWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 540px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
`
export const TopLine = styled.p`
  color: #01bf71;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
`
export const Heading = styled.h1`
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f7f8fa;
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
`

export const Progress = styled.div`
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
`
export const ProgressDone = styled.div`
  background: #01bf71;
  /* box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -5px #01bf71, 0 2px 5px #01bf71; */
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: ${(props) => (props.width ? props.width + '%' : 0)};
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s ease 0.3s;
`
```

[This is how it looks on on a computer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGcZ9.jpg)

[This is how it looks like on a mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEK4.jpg)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind from next time